# How to request an answer from a SOAP XML API?

Tags: php, xml, api, soap

I never worked with SOAP XML api before.

I read a couple of similar questions on SO but I can't get it to work.

Here's a simple request:

```
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance”
xmlns:xsd=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema” xmlns:soap12=”http://www.w3.org/2003/05/
soap-envelope”>
<soap12:Body>
<CheckDomainAvailability xmlns=”https://live.domainbox.net/”>
<AuthenticationParameters>
<Reseller>myreseller</Reseller>
<Username>myuser</Username>
<Password>mypassword</Password>
</AuthenticationParameters>
<CommandParameters>
<DomainName>checkadomain.co</DomainName>
<LaunchPhase>GA</LaunchPhase>
</CommandParameters>
</CheckDomainAvailability>
</soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

I've contacted them but they do not offer a PHP API.

I would like to use the SoapClient class built in PHP.

The question is: 
How do I send the request and print the answer?

Comment: I think there's no WSDL provided, the full docs are available here: https://admin.domainbox.net/docs/Domainbox-commands.pdf. I searched for WSDL and there's no reference about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like your WSDL is located at `https://live.domainbox.net/?WSDL`.

Here's an example using the native PHP SoapClient.

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://live.domainbox.net/?WSDL');

// populate the inputs....
$params = array(
    'AuthenticationParameters' => array(
        'Reseller' => '',
        'Username' => '',
        'Password' => ''
    ),
    'CommandParameters' => array(
        'DomainName' => '',
        'LaunchPhase' => ''
    )
);

$result = $client->CheckDomainAvailability($params);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: WOOOW How did you find that out? I'm so greatful, Thank you so much MrCode!

Comment: Uhoh, It's throwing an error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://live.domainbox.net/?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "https://live.domainbox.net/?WSDL". (I change the settings to reflect my credentials)

Comment: Have you got a quote in the link? If not then it's a server/network issue - your server doesn't have outside access so can't connect to the WSDL. Your host will be able to help with that.

Comment: Thanks , I'm updating SOAP extention, It looks like the one installed was corrupt. Thanks for your support.

Comment: The answer I receive now from the SOAP server is: Authentication Failed: Invalid Authentication Parameters. Tech support from API tells me to check my request. How can I know if the PHP script generate a valid XML request for this server?

Comment: Use this to see the last request: http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php

Answer (score 2):

To get this working I needed to change the first line to get the right version of soap to 1.2.
Also a previous comment

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://live.domainbox.net/?WSDL', array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));

// populate the inputs....
    $params = array(
       'AuthenticationParameters' => array(
          'Reseller' => '',
          'Username' => '',
          'Password' => ''
        ),
        'CommandParameters' => array(
            'DomainName' => '',
            'LaunchPhase' => ''
        )
    );

$result = $client->CheckDomainAvailability($params);

print_r($result);
```