# How to change the namespace sent with a SOAP request?

Tags: php, api, namespaces, soap-client

Related to this question: [How to request an answer from a SOAP XML API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844309/how-to-request-an-answer-from-a-soap-xml-api)

I have this PHP script sending the request with the required fields:

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://live.domainbox.net/?WSDL');
$params = array(
    'AuthenticationParameters' => array(
        'Reseller' => 'resellername',
        'Username' => 'myusername',
        'Password' => 'mypassword'
    ),
    'CommandParameters' => array(
        'DomainName' => 'mydomain.com',
        'LaunchPhase' => 'GA'
    )
);

$result = $client->CheckDomainAvailability($params);

print_r($result);
```

I get the following error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:VersionMismatch]
>
> Possible SOAP version mismatch: Envelope namespace
>   **http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/** was unexpected.
>
> Expecting **http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope**. in
>   /home/nosa/public_html/dev/check-domain-availability.php:20 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   /home/nosa/public_html/dev/check-domain-availability.php(20):
>
> SoapClient->__call('CheckDomainAvai...', Array) #1
>   /home/nosa/public_html/dev/check-domain-availability.php(20):
>   SoapClient->CheckDomainAvailability(Array) #2 {main} thrown in
>   /home/nosa/public_html/dev/check-domain-availability.php on line 20

I removed and recompiled apache to include the latest SOAP version available using WHM/cPanel.

My question is: 
How do I send the correct envelope namespace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When building your soap_client object, you can pass an option's array, by default, the version will be 1.1 as per php documentation.

The error you have seems to point out that the service might be SOAP 1.2 so you need to set it to 1.2...

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://live.domainbox.net/?WSDL', array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
```

Try that out!

Comment: Thank you Mathieu for this helpful answer, it's working. My first SOAP request ever! :)